# Select with ng-change causing all select fields automatically changed

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter, angular-ngmodel

I know that the title is a bit confusing but I've done my best to describe it in a sentence.  I want to use angular ng-change in select fields built with CodeIgniter. These selects are generated from an array. Everything is OK except these selects automatically select the same value for all select fields when I change one of them.

```
<?php $i=1; foreach ($data as $d) : ?>
Username: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $d->username ?>" /><br/>
Person: 
  <select ng-model="formData[<?php echo $i ?>].id" ng-change="updateUser()">
    <option value="1">Nina</option>
    <option value="2">Naila</option>
    <option value="3">Noni</option>
  </select><br/>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

So when I change the select by choosing Nina in first select field, for example, then all select fields automatically selects option Nina.

UPDATE:
In controller:

```
    angular.module('myApp')
.controller('userCtrl', function($scope,$http){

   $scope.formData = {};
   $scope.updateUser = function(){
      for (var i=1; i < $scope.formData.length; i++){
         console.log($scope.formData[i]);
      }
   }
```

With this, I got nothing when I examine it in console.

I tried to add attribute `name=id[]` on select but still no luck. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: That's because you are using the same model `ng-model="formData.id"` on all selects.

Comment: so, that's the problem. so can you tell me what I should do to avoid this to happen while I need to retrieve the value of selected option?

Comment: @Abaij Check out that answer and let me know if it answers your questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid mixing `php` views together with `AngularJS`, but as you can't change that you can try making your model index based (Since as I mentioned in the comment, the problem here is using the same [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) for the all [`select` elements](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)). Something like this could work:

```
<?php $index = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($data as $d) : ?>
Username: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $d->username ?>"/><br/>
Person:
<select ng-model="formData[<?php echo $index ?>].id" ng-change="updateUser()">
    <option value="1">Nina</option>
    <option value="2">Naila</option>
    <option value="3">Noni</option>
</select><br/>
<?php $index++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: yes, now they're not automatically changed but then i got value of `unidentified`. I don't know how to retrieve it in the angular controller.

Comment: In angularjs controller, you have to check `formData` array, it should contain all the values. Can you post some related code from the controller?

Comment: `formData` should be initialized as array `$scope.formData = [];`; why loop starts not from `0`, but from `1` here: `var i=1;`? Can you check generated markup as well, is it something like `ng-model="formData[0].id"`, `ng-model="formData[1].id"`, etc.? I'm not too good in `php` :)

Comment: @Abaij glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is due to the fact that you are using `formData.id` for each `ng-model`. So the `ng-model` will update to "1" (Nina) and all of the select elements using `formData.id` will change to "1" (Nina) as well.

```
<?php $index = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($data as $d) : ?>
Username: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $d->username ?>"/><br/>
Person:
<select ng-model="formData[<?php echo $index ?>].id" ng-change="updateUser()">
    <option value="1">Nina</option>
    <option value="2">Naila</option>
    <option value="3">Noni</option>
</select><br/>
<?php $index++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In your controller, initialize the formData array: `$scope.formData = [];` 
 and then formData[0].id will have the value for the first select, formData[1].id for the second, etc.

Comment: thanks for `ng-model="formData[<?php echo $index ?>].id"`. it is important.